# Majority of applications require explicit administrator rights

Tags: windows-7, uac

I have a windows 7 computer, and I've been having a really frustrating problem where the majority of applications require administrator rights that normally didn't on my previous windows 7 computer. The flash plugin for browsers (I have to start the browser with admin rights or flash doesn't work), most steam games, all java applications, unity, etc.

Furthermore, the UAC prompt doesn't come up for these applications, instead, I have to explicitly right click and select "Run as Administrator". If I don't, the program just doesn't run. Sometimes it says access is denied, sometimes it just fails silently with no errors. I haven't the slightest idea what's wrong, but it's very frustrating. Anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Is everything up to date? This certainly isn't the correct behavior.

Comment: As far as I know, yes. I have SP1 installed, along with all of the automated windows updates.

Comment: What about Firefox and Adobe? I seem to remember similar behaviour when Vista first was launched but went away as the developers learned to get around the better sandboxing of applications from the OS.

Comment: Both are up to date. Same happens on chrome and IE. Java is up to date as well, and the bug occurs for Java 5 through 7.

Comment: Is your account and **administrator account** type or a **standard user** type?  You may have to change your account type to administrator.

Comment: It's an administrator account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anybody cares, I did eventually figure out what the problem was. For some reason, `%APPDATA%` was set to *read only*. I had to take ownership of the folder and uncheck the read only option in properties, and the issue got fixed.